# iOS prefs url scheme for FaceID

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

What is the equivalent preferences url to TouchID to access the FaceID settings?

Access TouchID settings:

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE") {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Hint: try `FACEID_PASSCODE`. Note: Face-id is supported from iOS 11 and since iOS 11 apple has stopped navigation from Setting page. You can navigate to `setting` screen only. This code may not work in IOS 11